# Filtering down a Karate test response object to get a sub-list?

Tags: karate

Given this feature file:

```
Feature: test

  Scenario: filter response
    * def response =
    """
    [ 
        {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "a",
            "c": "a",
        },
        {
            "d": "ab",
            "e": "ab",
            "f": "ab",
        },
        {
            "g": "ac",
            "h": "ac",
            "i": "ac",
        }
    ]
    """
    * match response[1] contains { e: 'ab' }
```

How can I filter the `response` down so that it is equal to:

```
{
    "d": "ab",
    "e": "ab",
    "f": "ab",
}
```

Is there a built-in way to do this?   In the same way as  you can filter a List using a Java stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code:

```
Feature: test

  Scenario: filter response
    * def response =
    """
    [ 
        {
            "a": "a",
            "b": "a",
            "c": "a",
        },
        {
            "d": "ab",
            "e": "ab",
            "f": "ab",
        },
        {
            "g": "ac",
            "h": "ac",
            "i": "ac",
        }
    ]
    """
    * def filt = function(x){ return x.e == 'ab' }
    * def items = get response[*]
    * def res = karate.filter(items, filt)    
    * print res
```

Comment: yep ! and I recommend all to read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Comment: Thank you!  Just what I was looking for.